# EF Core: Possible FK cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm trying to link up two models in my database ("EventComments" and "ApplicationUsers") but i keep getting this error

> Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_EventComments_AspNetUsers_UserId' on table 'EventComments' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here are my models.

```
public class EventComment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public Event Event { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new HashSet<Event>();
    public ICollection<EventComment> EventComments { get; set; } = new HashSet<EventComment>();
}
```

Here is my Fluent API config

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            //user
            builder
                .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Events)
                .WithOne(b => b.User);

            builder
                .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.EventComments)
                .WithOne(b => b.User);

            builder
                .Entity<Event>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Comments)
                .WithOne(c => c.Event);
}
```

Specifying On Delete actions won't help in any way. Any suggestions would be appreciated.